# Need help on how to compute the fundamental group of a space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm studying for an oral qualifying exam and going through various past exams I find on the interwebs, including [this mock exam from the University of Bath](http://people.bath.ac.uk/masgks/MATH0040/mexam.ps) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204195101/http://people.bath.ac.uk/masgks/MATH0040/mexam.ps)). One of the questions seems like it should be rather straightforward, but it's giving me trouble. The question goes as follows:

Four small squares are cut out from a large square and discarded. The edges of what remains are then identified according to the labels in the figure. Find the fundamental group of the resulting space $X$. [You may wish to introduce more edges to help your calculations, but be careful not to make unauthorized identifications.]

[image: The Space X]

What would be a 'standard' approach to such a question? Here is what I have thought of so far and where I'm stuck:

- Using Van Kampen's: Intuitively, I'd like to set $U$ to be the interior of the large square and $V$ to be the enlargement of the boundary of the large square. Then $U \cap V \simeq S^1$, but I get tangled up when it comes to making the edge identifications and determining what to do with $U$, plus, after edge identifications, $U$ and $V$ interact, and so $U \cap V$ might not actually be $S^1$ as I've thought it was. Is Van Kampen's the way to go here?
- Since the hint mentions adding edges, is there some way to view this as a simplicial complex and compute the fundamental group from there? If so, how would I go about computing the fundamental group? (I am only familiar with computing homology for simplicial complexes, where I explicitly construct the boundary operators and compute the kernel/image of each to find the quotient groups.)

Thank you all for your help/advice!

---

**UPDATES:**

*New Approach #1:* I'm going to try and approach this by using [Proposition 1.26 in Hatcher](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf). That is, I'll view $X$ as attaching a 2-cell to the boundary in the picture (as suggested in the comments). First, I've added a basepoint $x_0 \in X$ and edges from this basepoint to the points labeled $C$ in each of the squares, as shown in this picture:

[image: Space with edge labels and added edges.]

After doing this, the boundary of the space turns into the following picture, and, by contracting the edge $k$ to a point, this space deformation retracts to the wedge of five circles. I've also listed the attaching map.

[image: Boundary of attached cell.]

By the proposition, we should be able to compute $\pi_1(X) = \pi_1(\partial X)/N$ where $N = \langle e\gamma e^{-1}f \gamma f^{-1} g \gamma g^{-1} h \gamma h^{-1} k \gamma^{-1} k^{-1} \rangle$. Writing $\pi_1(\partial X) = \langle \gamma, e, f, g, h \rangle$ and noting that $k$ is now the identity element, we get $\pi_1(X) = \langle \gamma, e, f, g, h \rangle / \langle e\gamma e^{-1}f \gamma f^{-1} g \gamma g^{-1} h \gamma h^{-1} \gamma^{-1} \rangle$.

Comment: Try Van Kampen again, but with $U$ as the light gray region (ie all but the squares) and $V$ as a union of enlargements of each square.

Comment: You can realize this space as a CW-complex by attaching one $2$-cell to a wedge sum of $5$ circles. The attaching map can be inferred from the diagram. This is one way to compute the fundamental group.

Comment: @aes - In order to use Van Kampen, we need $U \cap V$ to be path-connected, but the way I see it, with the $U$ and $V$ you've suggested, $U \cap V$ becomes five disjoint copies of $S^1$, and so it is not path-connected. Is there something I'm missing here with the identifications?

Comment: @AymanHourieh - I've added details to trying to implement the approach you suggested. I'd be very grateful if you had a chance to look it over and offer any suggestions, as I wasn't able to complete the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Rachel You're right. There is a version with disconnected intersection, or you can draw the extra edges you have, but that's equivalent to what you're currently doing. As to your current question, the 1-skeleton homotopy-equivalent to a wedge of circles.

Comment: @aes - Ah, I didn't know about the disconnected version. Thank you. Also, I see now how the shape deformation retracts to the wedge of five circles. I've finished writing the solution to the problem accordingly. Thank you again!

Comment: @Rachel: Instead of including your solution in the question, why not turn it into an answer? That way the question will no longer be on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give here another answer which I **think** is correct but I am not 100% sure. We will rely heavily on the first theorem at page 11 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, which basically allows us to do 2 things:

1. We can kill any contractible *line* without changing homotopy type
2. Instead of identifying two points we can just attach a $1$-cell at these two points.

Our first observation is that *after* identifying the edges, non of the vertices of the large square has been identifyied with eachother therefore we can collapse each edge of the edges $AB,BC,CD,DA$ to a point. The result space is *Space $1$*, where red points means identified  (see the picture).

Now, we get the homotopy equivalent *Space $2$* by replacing identifications by $1$-cells.

At last, we pull the outside point to the center, to get *Space $3$*, where the red lines are to be thought **above** the shape.

[image]

Now for the tricky part: The disc, without the red lines, deformation retracts to the wedge of $4$ circles. To picture this, imagine a strong gravity well at the center of the disk pulling everything radially at the center of the disc. Evertyhing either falls to the boundaries of the 4 existing holes or at the center of the disc, **including** the attaching points, therefore the red lines now became circles.

Therefore we end up wit the wedge of 8 circles and the fundamental group is $F_8$.